# "Save As..." won't work in IE8

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Part of the functionality of my intranet application is that a user needs to see some XML which has been generated. A new browser tab is opened, and the WebAPI controller streams XML.

This works fine, problem is when the user clicks on "Save As...", nothing happens.

If I place a static xml file on the server, browse to it and click "Save As..." then this works fine; so I don't see this as being caused by a group policy or desktop build error. This also works fine in a proper web browser.

The code to return the xml...

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = new StringContent(fpml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"),
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you trick IE into thinking that it has a file, rather than dynamic content, then the "Save As..." feature will work as expected.

This can be done by simply adding a filename into the URL, i.e.

Instead of

```
http://myhost/myapp/api/getFpmlApi/?TradeId=234234
```

use

```
http://myhost/myapp/api/getFpmlApi/Fpml.xml?TradeId=234234
```